# Text::Autoformat error in Perl

Tags: perl, autoformatting

I got the following Perl script that prints the content of the files in a directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Autoformat;

my $NER = "$ARGV[0]/Data/NER_$ARGV[1]";

foreach my $fp (glob("$NER/*")){
    if (-s $fp){
        # Open file to read
        open my $fz, "<", $fp or die;
        binmode $fz, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
        while(my $row = <$fz>){
            chomp($row);
            print "$row\n";
        }
        close $fz or die;
    }
}
```

The script runs OK but there is this warning every time a new file is opened:

```
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in join or string at /usr/local/share/perl5/Text/Autoformat/Hang.pm line 182, <$fz> line 1.

...
```

This is an example of the files that are being printed:

```
22-22   today   DATE
25-25   NY  LOCATION
```

Is this a bug in the [Text::Autoformat](http://p3rl.org/Text::Autoformat) module?

Comment: Where in the code do you call the `autoformat` subroutine?

Comment: This feels a bit like an `XY` problem. What are you trying to accomplish? Your source data doesn't seem to particularly need anything complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observe is normal and also you asked for it: [the `-w` option switch enables global warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-w*).

You're supposed to just use the lexical warnings (pragma `use warnings`) in Perl 5.6 and later, so remove the option switch.